# Is there a way to connect and view the files in a self Hosted Agent of Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, self, agent, hosted

I am pretty new to Azure Devops. Is there a way to connect and view the logs and the folders created in the self hosted agent of Azure devops pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

(i) While the build running on Azure devops  with Hosted Agent the only way to see the logs is to wait for **`console output.`**

(ii) After the build finished you can download the logs az **`zip`**

The logs are in the _diag folder (the folder exist in agnet root folder).

Also you can use the API to get the [`logs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Sajeetharan,I will show you the specific place to view the logs and folders in the page through the following image.
[image]
After the build pipeline finished, you can click into a build record. There is a **Logs** option in this record. You can click on the specific job to view the log, or you can click the **Download all logs** button to download the complete log to local view.
You can click on the file container which under **Build artifacts published** in the **Summary** to view folders.
In addition,using api:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.0` to get logs is also a good method.

Could you mark Sajeetharan's answer if it can be helpful to you.